# How can I verify if an object is visible on Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, visibility, windows-phone

I need to verify whether an object is visible or not, I tried to write this code, but It doesn't work (NullReferenceException):

```
if (PasswordConfirm.Visibility != Visibility.Collapsed)
                {
                    labelInsertPassword.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    PasswordConfirm.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
```

How can I do that?
Thank you!

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't an error description. Please note that the Visibility could also be `Visibility.Hidden`.

Comment: Sorry... It gives me a NullReferenceException, and no... Visibility.Hidden is not recongized...

Comment: In which method is this code located?

Comment: private void CheckBoxUnchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

Comment: If the NullReferenceException is thrown from the line `if (PasswordConfirm.Visibility != Visibility.Collapsed)` then there is only one thing that could be null and that is `PasswordConfirm`. You will need to provide quite a bit more code than this, including some xaml markup.

Comment: Here you are :) http://www.mediafire.com/?cf9ftxi0v7ny90w

Answer (score 3):

The following snippt works fine in my case.You need to show other code associating with that to get good solution..

```
  if (passwordBox1.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
        MessageBox.Show("Visible");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Not visible");
```

Comment: Thanks... I've uploaded the whole code here: mediafire.com/?cf9ftxi0v7ny90w

Comment: Though you not mentioned enough information and i can't see whole of your project,but the code which you share on that link,it seems to me that is a problem on this line bool PasswordOnLoad = (bool)MainPage.onLoad.settings["PasswordOnLoad"],always it returns a false value for which you above code(in else statement) won't work.So first check that value first,check whether it acts rightly as you want.